# Google BigQuery - Using wildcard table query with date partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use wildcard table functions to query bunch of date-partitioned tables.

This query works:

```
select * from `Mydataset.fact_table_1` where _partitiontime='2016-09-30' limit 10
```

This query does not work:

```
select * from `Mydataset.fact_table_*` where _partitiontime='2016-09-30' limit 10
```

Is this operation not supported?

If it is not supported what's the best way to read same day's data from multiple date-partitioned tables?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "does not work"? Do you get an error, or is the issue that the result is unexpected?

Comment: I get the error -" Unrecognized name: _partitiontime  " .. same works if I do not use wildcard character or do not use _partitiontime. I can not use both of them in same query.

Comment: I think if you use a wildcard table, you have to filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX` instead, or at least that's my interpretation of https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables. I'm not sure that you can use both `_TABLE_SUFFIX` and `_PARTITIONTIME` but I asked a coworker to confirm.

Comment: I am able to use TABLE_QUERY in legacy sql along with _PARTITIONTIME.   so if I want to list partitions for all tables -              select _partitiontime as pt from (TABLE_QUERY(Mydataset, 'table_id CONTAINS "fact_table_"')) group by 1

Comment: If I can use only _TABLE_SUFFIX how can I get data from multiple matching tables for a date range in day partitioned tables?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Unfortunately this is not supported in standard SQL for now, but this is a interesting and useful use case to support. I filed a feature request internally to track this work.

Comment: I have a question about the tables matched by the wildcard mydataset.fact_*. Are those tables date sharded? In other words, how are those tables related logically? Are the suffixes of those tables, dates or something more general like customer ids etc.?

Comment: And here's the link to the feature request FYI: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=728.

Comment: Thanks All, @Pavan table suffix is just IDs.. Table_1.. Table_2.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Following statement

```
select * from TABLE_QUERY(YOUR_DATASET,'table_id contains "fact_table_"') where _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP('2016-09-30')
```

Should do the trick

Comment: That works but I was looking for solution with standard_sql and not legacy sql.

Comment: hi @TimS have you found a solution yet to this using standard sql? I tried using UNION ALL but that is just too slow.